# How to run a Cucumber Step multiple times with different data?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber-java

I am trying to automate one scenario using Cucumber.

Step `Then Create item` actually takes values from first row only.

What I want to do is execute step `Then Create item` 2 times, before moving to step `Then assigns to CRSA`.

But my code is taking values from first row only (0P00A). How to take values from both rows?

```
Background: Application login
    Given User launch the application on browser
    When User logs in to application
   

     Scenario: Test
            Then Create item
              | Item ID    | Attribute Code | New Value | Old Value |
              | 0P00A      | SR             |  XYZ21    | ABC21     |
              | 0P00B      | CA             |  XYZ22    | ABC22     |
     Then assigns to CRSA




  @Then("Create item")
    public void createItem(DataTable dataTable) {
        
        List<Map<String, String>> inputData = dataTable.asMaps();
        
        }
```

Comment: shouldn't it be done like this? https://www.toolsqa.com/cucumber/data-driven-testing-using-examples-keyword/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use foreach like below:

```
List<Map<String, String>> inputData = dataTable.asMaps(); 
   
  for (Map<String, String> columns : inputData ) {

         columns.get("Item ID");
         columns.get("Attribute Code");

}
```